# How to get entire row of data from pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a .csv file that I need to search certain headers and parse out the data, such as gender.  Here I have code to get the gender from the gender column, but I need to append the entire row of the female column to a list, how do i do this?

```
data = pd.read_csv("PainReport2.csv") 
headers = list(data.columns.values.tolist())

for x in data["Gender(M/F)"].values:
    if(x == 'F'):
        print(x)
```

This prints out just the values of this column, how can I print out the values of just the female rows? I've tried to print data but it just prints the entire data set and not those with only female.

Comment: do `for x in data` instead, then test on `x["Gender"]`

Comment: `data[data['Gender(M/F)'] == 'F']`

Comment: maybe [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) helps you

Answer (score 0):

you can try :

```
data = pd.read_csv("PainReport2.csv") 
filter_data = data[data['Gender(M/F)']=='F']
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply filter to the lines you want with conditional indexing.

```py
data = pd.read_csv("PainReport2.csv") 
filtered_data = data[data["Gender(M/F)"]]
print(filtered_data)
```